# creating recursive function in r

Tags: r, recursion

```
set.seed(1)
x <- runif(50, 0, 1)
y <- runif(50, 0, 1)
df<-as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))

vall<-c(rep(0,50))
n<-4
theval <- function(data) {
 for (i in n:length(data$x)) {
   vall[i] <- 0.4*(data$x[i]/data$y[i]) + vall[i-1]*0.6
 }
 return(vall)
}

vall <- theval(df)
```

Hi,
I have a problem with some kind of recursive function in R. 
I want to derive a function which is calculated like following formula.

> z(t) = 0.4* (x(t) / y(t)) + 0.6*z(t-1) with  z(t)=0 when t < 3

My code give a reslut, but the result are wrong.

```
[1]  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.54579432  0.03226801  0.34139501  0.33139827  0.06531491  0.30135295
[10] -0.18739884
```

When I compute maunally, the first non-zero answer(the forth one) should be 0.2653642.
Could you tell me waht I was doing wrong?

Thx!

Comment: Is it `t < 3 ` or `t <= 3 `?

Comment: @Rui Barradas it is t<=3 sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function computes the formula in the question but it gives yet another result.

```
theval <- function(data, n) {
  z <- numeric(nrow(data))
  for (i in n:length(data$x)) {
    z[i] <- 0.4*(data$x[i]/data$y[i]) + 0.6*z[i - 1]
  }
  z
}

set.seed(1)
x <- runif(50, 0, 1)
y <- runif(50, 0, 1)
df <- data.frame(x, y)

z3 <- theval(df, n = 3)
z4 <- theval(df, n = 4)

head(z3)
#[1] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.5230378 1.7978388 2.2200992 4.9449051
head(z4)
#[1] 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1.484016 2.031806 4.831929
```

Comment: @눈웃음짓는붉은여우 In the formula it's a *division*, in the comment you are *subtracting*.

Comment: your code is right I guess. I computed wrong one.